# Xamarin Forms Android cannot find dll

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I just finished building an app in xamarin forms for iOS, and now am in the process of porting to Android. I'm able to load up my initial login screen, but when I attempt to login, I get the following error:

```html
[Mono] Image addref System.Net.Http[0x99b7b5e0] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0x9e5e8c00]: 1
[Mono] Assembly System.Net.Http[0x99b7b5e0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT module 'System.Net.Http.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/varmory.Android/lib/System.Net.Http.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref varmory[0xac340d60] -> System.Net.Http[0x99b7b5e0]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0x99b7b5e0] -> mscorlib[0xac3404c0]: 59
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll
```

Am I missing some step in which I need to initialize/link these libraries manually?

Comment: `/data/data/varmory.Android/lib/System.Net.Http.dll.so` what?

Where did you get this? Always be nugettin'.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the reason I was getting this error was because I did not have method stubs for my custom rendered classes. Once I added the Custom renderer classes and implemented the OnElementChanged method my app was able to run, albeit with styling issues.